# What is the TWIG equivalent for XSLT's document() function?

Tags: xml, xslt, twig

I am rewriting my .XSL template into a .TWIG template and I run into a problem.
I don't know how to handle node selection from a specific data source represented by an .XML file.
Below is my .XSL code snippet that I am trying to rewrite into TWIG ↓

```
<!-- firstly I am selecting my .XML file that contains data -->
<xsl:variable name="subscriptionData" select="document('../xml/subscriptions.xml')" />

<!-- then I am selecting a node in that .XML file -->
<xsl:variable name="data" select="$subscriptionData/root/subscription[position() = 1]" />

<!-- finally I can print out a specific property -->
<xsl:value-of select="$data/title" />
```

This is my attempt to rewrite that into TWIG - as You can see I don't know how to select that .XML file as a data source (line 1) ↓

```
{# I don't know how to select that .XML file that contains data #}
{% set subscriptionData = ??????? %}

{# selecting a node inside .XML #}
{% set data = subscriptionData.root.subscription[0] %}

{# printing out a specific property #}
{{ data.title }}
```

Comment: You don't import data inside a twig template, you pass data into it. That is, you call `Twig_TemplateWrapper::render(data)`. Cf. https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/api.html#rendering-templates

Comment: @Dormilich That looks so complicated. Is there any other way pls?

Comment: You find a simple method call complicated? (It only looks complicated because I don't know your backend). In the end, you cannot translate XSLT 1:1 into Twig as both systems have different approaches on how to do things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't import data inside a twig template, you pass data into it. That is, you call `Twig_TemplateWrapper::render(data)`. Cf. [twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/api.html#rendering-templates](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/api.html#rendering-templates)